# Laravel: Using whereBetween is returning undefined

Tags: php, laravel-5

I store a timestamp as a string and pass it in to `getOrders`.   I am logging `$time` so I can see it's valid and being logged as a string timestamp.

I am getting `undefined` returned back but I can't see how.  I am using `count($paidOrders) > 0 ? array_values($customers) : []` in the return to protect me from getting back an empty value so that if there are no $paidOrders, I get back an empty array of `[]`, which I would expect if it queries and gets not matching orders within those times.

```
public function getOrders($time)
{
    try {
        // $time is a timestamp in string format; ex: "1601339962"

        $paidOrders = Order::whereBetween('orders.created_at', [ Carbon::createFromTimestamp($time) , Carbon::now()])->get()->all();
        $customers = [];

        if (count($paidOrders) > 0) {
            foreach ($paidOrders as $paidOrder) {
                if(!isset($customers[$paidOrder->customer_id])) {
                    $customers[$paidOrder->customer_id]['customer_name'] = $paidOrder->ship_name;
                    $customers[$paidOrder->customer_id]['customer_id'] = $paidOrder->customer_id;
                    $customers[$paidOrder->customer_id]['total'] = $paidOrder->subtotal;
                }
                else{
                    $customers[$paidOrder->customer_id]['total'] += $paidOrder->subtotal;
                }
                $customers[$paidOrder->customer_id]['orders'][] = $paidOrder->id;
            }
        }

        return [
            'paidOrdersDuringStream' =>  count($paidOrders) > 0 ? array_values($customers) : [],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you returning `undefined`?  If the return of the function call `getOrders()` it may be throwing an exception, depending on your `catch/finally` process.

Comment: For clarification `Query::whereBetween();` would return `Query`, then chained to `Query::get()` would return a `Collection` and `Collection::all()` would return an `array`. So it appears that something is throwing an exception and we can't see the `catch` portion handling the exception.

Comment: that is exactly what is happening.  I saw the response was `200` but didn't check the contents and the `catch` was getting triggered.  It was stating `createTimestamp()` expects 1 parameter to be an integer and was getting a string so I just needed to cast the timestamp string to an int.  Thank you!